# Driver Power State Failure Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bsod

I have a laptop **ASUS X550JK**, after installing the **Windows 10**, installing the missing drivers & programs, I get the **Driver Power State Failure BSOD**, I tried to update all drivers & change some power settings, but unfortunately, the **BSOD** still appears.

[image]

**NOTE 1:**

1. The **BSOD** appears randomly, sometimes appears after the welcome
   screen, or after using the computer for some time.
2. Before the **BSOD** appears, I noticed the fan makes a noisy sound.

**NOTE 2:**

I've tried to install Linux to check if this issue happens with the Windows 10 only, I tried with **Linux Ubuntu 19.04** & **Linux Mint 19.2**, and everything works just fine, I've used the computer almost 3h without any issues.

**My pc specs & informations :**

**Asus x550JK**

**CPU:** Intel Core i5-4200H

**GPU :** NVIDIA GeForce GTX 850M

**RAM:** 8GB

---

**CPU TEMP during idle** : 42°c - 50°c

dmp files :

[image]

Comment: Works with Linux ; not with Windows suggests BIOS and Firmware is probably OK.  in Windows, update Chipset, Video, and power management drivers from the Manufacturer's support website, restart and try again.

Comment: @John thank you for your comment, I will do that